# how to use showdown.js in scalajs?

Tags: scala.js, showdown

I want use [showdown.js](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) library on my scalajs project.
How could I use scalajs to replace javascript code:

```
var converter = new showdown.Converter(),
    text      = '#hello, markdown!',
    html      = converter.makeHtml(text);
```

I have find a dependencies with `jsDependencies += "org.webjars.bower" % "github-com-showdownjs-showdown" % "1.4.3" / "1.4.3/showdown.js" commonJSName "Showdown"`, but its not enough. Should I write a js.native binding to the library refer in [scala.js document](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/dependencies.html)?

A example is welcome! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should indeed write an `@js.native` binding for the library, unless you find a published library that does it for you.

For the small example that you show, the binding would look like this:

```scala
@js.native
@JSGlobal("showdown.Converter")
class Converter extends js.Object {
  def makeHtml(text: String): String = js.native
}
```

which then allows you to write

```scala
val converter = new Converter()
val text = "#hello, markdown!"
val html = converter.makeHtml(text)
```

Comment: Seems great!also hope scala.js compile could auto generate bind class from a js file or a url(js cdn) in the future.